Whining sound coming from the attic when flushing toilet
We recently replaced a leaky PRV that was located in the attic of our home. Since replacing the PRV we have noticed a humming, whiny sound that comes only when flushing the toilet.
Went into the attic to investigate and the sound seems to come from the tubing which the water flows through. We are using pex piping.
Any ideas to remedy this?  Will a water hammer arrestor help with this type of noise?

PRV are usually mounted on water heater, not on toilet plumbing
